# Schedule loads of Files from FTP server into google Cloud storage

Tags: google-cloud-platform, storage

What is the best way to schedule a daily load of files which are uploaded on a ftp server into a google cloud storage?

What steps are need to make this possible?

1. Move files that are in ftp server to google cloud storage
2. Schedule this job at a specific time each day.

Comment: If you are on Linux, `cron` can do the job for you. But: It's a bad idea to use FTP, because it is unencrypted!

Answer (score 0):

You can use Cloud Storage [FUSE](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gcs-fuse?hl=en) tools that allows you to mount the GCS bucket as a file system on Linux or MacOS systems. To [install](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcsfuse/blob/master/docs/installing.md) FUSE please follow the documents.

Now you need to developed an script which will transfer files from the VM to the Storage (mount) and for scheduling this job you can use [cron](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/crontab.5.html) job.

Comment: Please use this link to [install FUSE](https://github.com/libfuse/libfuse/blob/master/README.md)

Comment: @JoseLuisDelgadillo - can you explain why in more detail?

Comment: I added the last link because the link in the answer was broken.