# Using Google Cloud Storage meet error 500 in website which hosted on amazon server

Tags: php, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I'm a new user for using the Google cloud storage platform. I had successfully created the bucket locally by xampp and composer. But when i moved to the whole files to my server and it shows some error.

Is there any way to solve this? Because my idea is try to as a simple form for people to download and upload image through my website but mostly google documents are point to do it locally.
Below provided my code.

p/s:bucket can be created when i put the new name, but when i type the same name, it return error 500 instead of the name creation redundant fatal error.

[image: my current code]

[image: the error]
[image: my server side]

Comment: Error 500 is definitely an authentication error. You should check that the permissions on your service account is sufficient or json key directory is valid.

Comment: Do you want to mount the GCS bucket to other server or only want to move the files from the bucket to the other server?

Comment: @kallusis369 Hi, i managed to create the bucket by adding 'keyFilePath'=>'mykey.json' to the storageClient() but it can work only once. Is there any permenant way to do it?

Comment: @Mahboob I want to mount he GCS bucket in my server so that I can allow user upload and download items actions to my GCS bucket

Comment: @RexYou You can follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65396923/11866104) if you want to mount a bucket in Linux or MacOS systems

Comment: @RexYou If you want people can download bucket's file directly, You should use [signed url](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/signed-urls).

Comment: @Mahboob actually I want to let user can modify their bucket and files through my sample website so after I created local files then I moved all the files to my server but it keep appear 500 error. May I know is there any ways to avoid this error?

Comment: @kallusis369 this is a good option but what i try to let the user handle by themselves rather that keep calling me to generate key for them. My current page can creat new bucket after i keep changing the bucket name but it didnt come out the fatal error that mentioned bucket created. Is there any way to solve this?

Comment: @RexYou I suspect the permissions of service account is cause of problem. What permissions do your service account have?

Comment: @kallusis369 i thinked is normal permission. I just set as project owner. Is there any extra setting I need to setup for prevent error 500?

Comment: @RexYou Then ACLs could be a problem. Check created buckets ACL list. Is it fine-grained? or uniform? If fine-grained enabled, check members of permission section whether your service account is enrolled or not.

Comment: @kallusis369 sorry for the late reply. All I created are fine-graned, all accounts are project owner permission. But I'm curious one thing, if i didn't host my website on google cloud, does it means I cannot use the google cloud storage?

Comment: @RexYou You can use GCS objects fort your website hosted anywhere. To do that, it is important that you must authenticate your credentials via service accounts.

Comment: @kallusis369 For the current account that I used already authenticate but I had discussed with the GCS support and they suspect is that the error might caused by my hosting server which host on amazon. I might need to find a way to disable error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after few days tested, I had successfully to get correct return error.
Below provided my code which using try catch statement.

```
try {
     $bucket = $storage->createBucket($bucketName);
     echo 'Bucket ' . $bucket->name() . ' created.';
     return $bucket;

     } catch (Exception $e) {
                    
        echo "<br>";
        echo 'Caught exception: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";

  }
```

If you got any related solution please let me know. Thanks.